# Upgraded from Spring 3 to Spring 5 - and now errors with autowiring

Tags: java, spring, weblogic12c, weblogic-10.x, spring-3

There's a project to upgrade Java, weblogic and as it eventually turned out spring in one of our web apps.
Used to be java 6, weblogic 10 and spring 3.
Moving to java 8, weblogic 12 and spring 5.

After a lot of dependency hell at compile time and having to refactor around some depreciated spring classes I've got it to build.

And this when the real issues started.

When deploying the app I'm getting the following exception.

> <02-Apr-2019 10:14:56,294 o'clock IST>     <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '92' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <37efec1d-3b6b-481e-a623-5c66ebd12f27-0000005d> <1554196496294> <[severity-value: 16] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] >  ' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=healthPlanCheckoutFunnelStateHolderMapper)}.
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'findAPlanCheckoutController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'funnelStateHolderMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.vhi.web.common.mappers.FunnelStateHolderMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=healthPlanCheckoutFunnelStateHolderMapper)}
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1395)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
>     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
>     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:705)
>     at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
>     at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
>     at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
>     at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:251)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:204)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:189)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1921)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3101)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1843)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:884)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
>     at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
>     at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752)
>     at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:66)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
>     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
>     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:631)
>     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
>     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
>     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:348)
>     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:907)
>     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1468)
>     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:459)
>     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
>     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217)
>     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
>     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
>     at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:678)
>     at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
>     at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
>     at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
>     at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
>     at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:652)
>     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
>     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
>   Caused By: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.vhi.web.common.mappers.FunnelStateHolderMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=healthPlanCheckoutFunnelStateHolderMapper)}
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1654)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1213)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1395)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
>     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
>     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
>     at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:705)
>     at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
>     at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
>     at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
>     at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:251)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:204)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:189)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1921)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3101)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1843)
>     at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:884)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
>     at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
>     at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752)
>     at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:66)
>     at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
>     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
>     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:631)
>     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
>     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
>     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:348)
>     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:907)
>     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1468)
>     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:459)
>     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
>     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217)
>     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
>     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
>     at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:678)
>     at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
>     at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
>     at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
>     at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
>     at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:652)
>     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
>     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)

The component is:

```java
@Component
@Qualifier("healthPlanCheckoutFunnelStateHolderMapper")
public class HealthPlanCheckoutFunnelStateHolderMapper extends CommonHealthCheckoutFunnelStateHolderMapper<HealthPlanCheckoutBean>
{
    @Override
    protected HealthPlanCheckoutBean createBean() {
        return new HealthPlanCheckoutBean();
    }
}
```

and the autowiring of that component is:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("healthPlanCheckoutFunnelStateHolderMapper")
private FunnelStateHolderMapper<HealthPlanCheckoutBean, HealthPlanFunnelStateHolder> funnelStateHolderMapper;
```

The FunnelStateHolderMapper interface

```
/**
 * Interface defines methods for mapping to and from a {@link FunnelStateHolder}. This is the top level mapper that
 * should be used by each controller for handling GET and POST requests. The implementation may delegate to other
 * underlying mappers but this should always be the interface to which the controller talks.
 */
public interface FunnelStateHolderMapper<B, F extends FunnelStateHolder> {

    B toScreenBean(F funnelStateHolder);

    F fromScreenBean(F funnelStateHolder, B screenBean);
}
```

There is a component-scan in the configuration that includes the package that this code is in.

This worked fine with spring 3 but since changing to spring 5 this issue is occurring.
I suppose its possible that some refactoring I had to do to get it to compile has caused this issue but I don't think so.  None of the files that the above code is in have been updated.

I haven't had to update any of the spring config either up to now.
Is there a difference in how spring 3 and spring 5 search for components?

Comment: Try removing `@Qualifier("healthPlanCheckoutFunnelStateHolderMapper")` from `HealthPlanCheckoutFunnelStateHolderMapper` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The field

```
private FunnelStateHolderMapper<...> funnelStateHolderMapper;
```

**isn't** of the same type of the `@Component`/`@Qualifier` annotated class

```
HealthPlanCheckoutFunnelStateHolderMapper
```

You cannot expect Spring to `@Autowire` something that would throw a **compile/runtime error**.

---

If `HealthPlanCheckoutFunnelStateHolderMapper` is part of a hierarchy, please show that.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the app. I hadn't really worked on it prior to this.

The HealthPlanCheckoutFunnelStateHolderMapper does extend a class that has 3 levels of abstraction below it and I'm completely thrown by it - I don't understand the necessity for the complexity.

I didn't think I could could put in whole files due to the guidelines?

Comment: @Kevin have you modified other pieces of this code/classes? Were you using XML in Spring 3?

Comment: @Kevin can you post the signature of `CommonHealthCheckoutFunnelStateHolderMapper`?

Comment: @Kevin anway, I think this has to do with type erasure. Your hierarchy is too deep.

Comment: `public abstract class CommonHealthCheckoutFunnelStateHolderMapper<B extends CommonHealthCheckoutBean>
        extends
        AbstractCheckoutBeanMapperTemplate<PolicyHolderDetailsBean, AdditionalPersonBean, B, CommonHealthFunnelStateHolder>`

Comment: I haven't updated any of these classes or the classes that are extended/implemented

Comment: There was no XML bean definition in spring 3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191095/discussion-between-lppedd-and-kevin).